# How to create the child before the second parent, the latter will be "pre-filled" with a child's attribute - ruby on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, nested-forms

Here how I would like things to work. I am not sure it is possible this way… 
The `Seller` registers and can create a `Resa` which attribute is `request_email`: [DONE]
 
Once the `Resa` is created, an e-mail is sent to the `request_email` [DONE] asking to click on the link to register as a `Buyer`. 
In this `Buyer` registration form, the e-mail field should be pre-filled with the `request_email` from the `Resa`. Once the buyer is saved, the Resa object should see its attribute `buyer_id` be updated from `nil`to the `id` of the `Buyer` object created. 

Devise was added to `Seller` and `Buyer`.

**Questions:** are the following models and associations correctly designed to allow the process described above? 
If yes, how to pass the resa_id and the request_email in the link for creating the Buyer (pre-filled form) ?

Please feel free to suggest a smarter way to do things if you feel this is the wrong way.

**models/seller.rb**

```
  class Seller < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :resas
    has_many :buyers, :through => :resas
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  end
```

**models/resa.rb**

```
  class Resa < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :seller
    belongs_to :buyer
  end
```

**models/buyer.rb**

```
  class Buyer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :resas
    has_many :sellers, :through => :resas
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  end
```

**controllers/resas_controller.rb**

```
    class ResasController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_resa, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
      before_action :authenticate_seller!
    …

    def create
        @resa = current_seller.resas.new(resa_params)
        @resa.request_status = "Pending"
        #@resa.seller_id = current_seller.id
        respond_to do |format|
          if @resa.save
            ResaMailer.request_mail(@resa).deliver
            format.html { redirect_to @resa, notice: 'Resa was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @resa }
          else
            format.html { render action: 'new' }
            format.json { render json: @resa.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
    …
    end
```

**controllers/buyers_controller.rb**

```
  class BuyersController < ApplicationController
def create
@buyer = Buyer.new(buyer_params)
@resa = Resa.find(params[:resa_id])

respond_to do |format|
  if @buyer.save
    format.html { redirect_to @buyer, notice: 'Buyer was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @buyer }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @buyer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
 end
end
```

Please let me know if you need further informations.

Comment: J'ai pas compris. Which part is not working exactly? Can you clarify the question please

Comment: And also parse your `RegistrationsController` if you overwritten it (cause it seems that your question is about registration, right?)

Comment: When I say register, this is simply creating the object Seller or Buyer. I added informations, hoping it is clearer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your `ResaMailer.request_mail` is generating the link for the buyer registration. So in this link you can add a token

```
http://your.site/buyer/new?token=abcdef
```

The idea is to generate a token, store it in a table (perhaps your `resas` table) and along in the same record you can store the other fields you will need to retrieve during the buyer registration (like `request_email` for example)

Then in your `BuyersController` `new` action you can fetch the data using that token, and pre-fill the form.

```
class BuyersController
  def new
    @resa = Resa.find_by(token: params[:token])
    # Use @resa to prefil the form in `new` action
  end
end
```

As for the `buyer_id` you can't get a valid id before the record is created, but if your concern is to link the `resa` record with the newly created `buyer`, you can use the token I mentioned earlier to retrieve the `resa` record's id at the time of the buyer registration, then update this record with the newly created `buyer` id.

Hope it's clear, let me know.

Comment: Benjamin thank you for your reply.  I certainly have to look into the concept of token and using them in Rails.  
`request_email`is already an attribute of `Resa`so it is stored in this table.  
To make things even simpler, can we replace `token` with `request_email`? `http://your.site/buyer/new?request_email=email@gmail.com    
Then, how can I fetch the e-mail address in BuyersController in Rails 4?

Comment: Sure you can, as long as you have a way to retrieve your data when the person that clicked the link arrive in your form. I would personally prefer using token instead of an email because I find it more secure, see how devise work with tokens for confirmation and password. But both work, and it's up to the designer of the application

Comment: See my edit for a show case of data retrieval (used token for consistency, works also with request_email)

Comment: To save the `buyer_id` freshly created in the `resa` record, should I have to add an attribute to store the `token` in `Buyer` ? for example `last_token_resa`

Comment: You can mimic what device does, keep your :token following the flow from the new to the create (and through redisplay of form during validation error) so in your create you can get your resa record and link to your newly created buyer record

Comment: Thank you Benjamin. I don't know how I can do that (keeping the token from new to create). Can you recommend a page where this method is used (as an example) ?